# JavaScript Issue on Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, position, z-index

I have a table of results from a database and then I have the following JavaScript that allows a user to click a table row, which will then take them to the correct record.

```
var pathName = window.location.pathname;

$('table tr').click(function(event) {
    var modelId = $('section').attr('data-id');
    var dataType = $(this).attr('data-type');
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    if(pathName === '/accounts/' + modelId) {
        if(dataType === 'contact') {
            pathName = '/contacts';
        } else if(dataType === 'note') {
            pathName = '/notes';
        } else if(dataType === 'opportunity') {
            pathName = '/opportunities';
        }
    } else if(pathName === '/contacts/' + modelId) {
        if(dataType === 'note') {
            pathName = '/notes';
        } else if(dataType === 'opportunity') {
            pathName = '/opportunities';
        }
    } else if(pathName === '/events/' + modelId) {
        pathName = '/delegates';
    }

    var showUrl = pathName + '/' + id;

    if(id === undefined) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        window.location = showUrl;
    }
});
```

THat works great, except that in each table row, I have a form with a button to delete the record, which when clicked bring up a popup. Unfortunately, because now the table rows are clickable to take the user to the correct records, if they click the delete button it attempts to show the popup but then quickly redirects to the record show view.

I'm thinking this could possibly be fixed with CSS but I've tried position: relative; and z-indexing to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: By using `.attr('data-id')` you're not taking advantage of one of the benefits of the data atrribute. It's more efficient to use `.data('id')`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I&#039;m not after the id (name) of the element, I'm after an id for the record generated using PHP. The #id is completely different.

Comment: Yes, the `#id` is completely different.  Sounds like you need to read up on the data attribute!  `.data('id')` has nothing to do with the id attribute.  Rather, it searches for the data value you assigned with the attribute 'data-id'.  Likewise, instead of `.attr('data-type')`, you should be using `.data('type')`.  Anytime you use an attribute that begins with 'data-' you are using a special feature of html5 that stores these values, and they are best accessed by using the `.data()` method. See api.jquery.com/data/#data2 for documentation.

Comment: Ah OK! Didn't realise. THank you. I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `click event for the form button` write this piece of code.

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

It will stop the event from bubbling to the parent.

Comment: Excellent, this worked perfectly. I wasn't aware of this function, very useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Gaz.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the click event of the button in order to not propagate it to the table row.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop propagation on the click of the button:

```
element.click(function (e) {  // 'element' would be your button/a/input
    e.stopPropagation();
```

I've created a little fiddle to demonstrate how this works:  http://jsfiddle.net/PVvfV/.